# Hyper-v issue with docker after enabling hyper-v

Tags: docker, hyper-v

I disabled hyper-v for a reason then enabled it again. But docker could not start saying "Cannot enable hyper-v service". I did disabled and re-enable hyper-v in windows, it did not work. I did enable virtualization in bios, it did not work. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled docker and installed it again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Before installing Docker, Hyper-v must be installed then you can install docker.

Answer (score 0):

Docker problems may be caused by an error in Hyper-V.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIpsY.png)

so enter to "activer ou désactiver des fonctionnalités windows" and enable hyper-v also reboot system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bkOo.jpg)

if you have an MSI laptop you can just tape delete on the keyboard and enter to the bios and enable virtualization and hyper-v

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAs7I.png)